# Is it acceptable to splice a circuit in two opposite directions for outdoor recepts/lighting?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

Per the 2011 NEC, is it acceptable to...

1. Splice a circuit (using a junction box indoors) as long as I leave it exposed, use the correct wire connectors, and have it covered?
2. Use this run one side of the spliced wire to a pair of GFCI outlets at the base of my house(outside), and the other to a switch (inside) and then to a flood light (outside)?

So can I splice and can I have outdoor receptacles on same circuit as outdoor light?

Also, If anyone knows what section either of these are covered in the 2011 NEC and could tell me that would be great too!

Comment: There is no problem with what you want to do. Though if I posted all the relevant code sections, I don't think it would be considered "fair use" anymore. See NEC chapters 1-4.

Comment: What wouldn't be considered "fair use" anymore? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I posted the entirety of chapters 1-4 of NEC, I don't think that would fall under [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Comment: Ah I see. Ok, well thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can't post what is not there. There is nothing prohibiting this and as Tester states, quite a bit of chapters 1 thru 3 apply in general, with spots in 4. 
The NEC is NOT written in a way that you can simply look up a specific job you are doing. It can be very general and very broad, yet also specific on certain things.

I realize this question is 3 months old and the project likely done by now, but what is being proposed in the original post is fine.

Comment: Yes this OK and there is nothing in the code that will say that in one spot.  It's not only OK but very common.

Answer (score -1):

The wiring code may also be locally governed.  However, I have lived in houses that have outside outlets on the same circuit with inside lights and outlets. This has always made me mildly uncomfortable, because of lightning strike issues, so I have modified that sort of wiring where I can do it without major rewiring; especially when expensive electronics are involved.

Comment: The fact that a circuit is shared between outdoor and indoor outlets is fine. Lightning will have no different effect on either.